# ¿Cómo redirigir con una JsonResponse en Django?

Tags: json, django, paypal

Estoy haciendo pagos con PayPal, todo funciona bien pero quiero que cuando la transacción se finalize me redirija a otra página con los datos de la compra que he realizado.

De momento tengo esto en views.py

```
def detalles(request):
    date = datetime.now()
    user = request.user
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    trayecto = Trayecto.objects.get(id = body['productId'])
    registro = Pago(
        destinatario = body['destinatario'],
        comprador = user,
        trayecto = trayecto,
        cantidad = body['cantidad'],
        fecha_pago = date,
        )

    registro.save()
    return JsonResponse('Pago completado', safe = False)
```

También lo he intentado con render_to_response pero al parecer ahora está deprocated ¿Hay alguna manera de reirigir y pasar datos?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Que librería utilizas para hacer las transacciones? django-paypal?

Comment: las transacciones se realizan por javascript